# How I solve the "mismatch in operand sizes" error?

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16

```
[org  0x0100]

num: db 0
factorial: dw 1

VUID: db 1,8,2,1,9,3,6
    mov bx, 0
jmp start

fact:   mov ax, byte[num]
fact_loop: mul word[factorial]

    sub ax, 1
    cmp ax, 0
    jp fact_loop
    ret

start:  mov bx, 0
    mov cx, [VUID+bx]
    add bx, 1
    shr cx, 1
    jc start
    mov [num], cx

    call fact

mov ax, 0x4c00
int 0x21
```

After assembling: 
`as02.asm: 10: error: mismatch in operand sizes`

Comment: `mov ax, byte[num]` <-- The size of `ax` is 16 bits. The size of a byte is 8 bits. It's not clear what you wanted to do. Look up `movzx` and `movsx` in the instruction set reference.

Comment: Write a subroutine that will find the first even number from an array of  VU ID=1821936 and calculate its factorial.